# Hudson plugin installation

Tags: hudson, hudson-plugins

I am trying to install `M2release plugin` in `Hudson`. 
I cannot install plugin using `Hudson` plugin update page due to lack of proxy settings. So i downloaded hpi file and used upload plugin option to deploy it.

Now `Hudson` home[directory] is showing the plugin inside plugin directory but i can't see the plugin in list of installed plugins on `Hudson` UI also plugin is not available on job configuration page. I hvae already bounced hudson server twice.

What am i missing here? Any additional steps are needed to install plugin manually?

Answer (score 0):

Your steps seem fine.Since M2release plugin has moved to Jenkins now, so make sure you downloaded the compatible version with Hudson.